# Adicionar time a um iframe no JS

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema e preciso que o JavaScript adicione o tempo entre o final de carregamento da página e o clique no conteúdo do iframe. Tentei usar o código abaixo, a var myInterval, porém no no iframe fica apenas '1', ou seja, ele não atualiza com o passar dos segundos. Após a página carregada pelo que parece o time ('&t=' + myInterval + ') fica com o número 1 estático.

```
if(!window.alreadyIncluded) {
    var t = 0;

    var time = 0;
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        ++time;
    }, 1000);

    var divList = document.getElementsByClassName('network');
    for (var i = divList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        t++;

        var rf = document.referrer;
        var lh = window.location.host;

        var slot = divList[i].getAttribute('data-ad-s');
        var client = divList[i].getAttribute('data-ad-c');
        var width = divList[i].offsetWidth;
        var height = divList[i].offsetHeight;

        divList[i].innerHTML = ('<iframe id="ad_iframe_' + t + '" name="ad_iframe_' + t + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="<?php echo $site->getSiteURL(); ?>/page/generate.php?s=' + slot + '&c=' + client + '&lh=' + lh + '&rf=' + rf + '&t=' + myInterval + '"></iframe>');
    }
    window.alreadyIncluded = true;
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas fazer o myInterval continuar atualizando a cada segundo mesmo após o load completo da página, mas não ele continua estático em 1, alguma ideia?

Comment: Amigo, o loop ocorre aqui dentro `var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        ++time;
    }, 1000);` o resto não irá se repetir mesmo

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer para que o myInterval continuasse a contar?

Comment: O valor acrescido no loop é o da `var time` o `myInterval` não possuí valor é apenas uma referência, na verdade não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer.. Ele está contando, variável `time` é atualizada a cada segundo

Comment: O que quero é que quando alguém clique no conteúdo do iframe, o php dê get na quantidade de segundos que se passou entre o carregamento do JS e o clique do visitante, entendeu? Quando eu coloco ' + time + ' ao invés do myInterval o $_GET['t'] retorna 0. (estou usando o die($_GET['t']) para verificar isso).